# 'int' object is not callable error while calling a function from another file | python | flask

Tags: python, function, class, flask, self

I am trying to create a speedtest website
SO I have a file speedtester.py in src folder-

```
import speedtest

st = speedtest.Speedtest()

class speed:
    def __init__(self):
        st.get_servers()
        best = st.get_best_server()
        speed_dict = st.results.dict()
        self.download = (speed_dict['download']) #/1024/1024:.2f
        self.upload = (speed_dict['upload'])
        self.ping = (speed_dict['ping'])
        self.host_info = (f"{best['host']} located in {best['country']}")
        self.ip = (speed_dict['client']['ip'])

    def download(self):
        return (f"Download speed is {self.download}")
    def upload(self):
        return self.upload
    def ping(self):
        return self.ping
    def host_info(self):
        return self.host_info
    def ip(self):
        return self.ip
```

I am importing this file in my app.py file-

```
from src.speedtester import speed
from flask import *

@app.route("/speedtest")
def speedtesting():
    st = speed()
    return st.download()
```

But when I am going to `localhost:5000/speedtest` its saying-

```
  File "/home/indo/Documents/Projects/Rexians-Web/app.py", line 28, in speedtesting
    return st.download()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Why is this saying if I am calling a function, and not a integer?

Comment: You have a method called `download` as well as an `int` instance variable, also named `download`. Rename one.

Comment: ONe more thing, Why everytime download and upload is showing 0?? (It maybe related to [speedtest pacakage](https://pypi.org/project/speedtest-cli/) )

Comment: Please ask only one question per question!